# Index page doesn't work but api works on AWS beanstalk Sprint Boot

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a spring boot application to aws.

I changed the port to 5000 via application.properties
Now, `url/api/hello` works fine but `url/` doesn't work

I am getting a white label error.

```
package com.example.package-name;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan()
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>package-name</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?
Is there anything wrong with the main Starter file?

> Note: Everything works fine locally, the error page is loading instead
>   of index page only in AWS

Answer (score 0):

I assume you deploy in aws elastic beanstalk tomcat server, please make sure access via beanstalk URL which will give you after uploading jar/war, generally whitespace error gives you whenever you try to access wrong URL/wrong parameters, if possible provide details with screenshots.